# SOLR index implementation and configuration to support different pricing for millions of records

Tags: apache, solr, lucene

I have some knowledge using SOLR/Lucene, but really never worked extensively.

We have multiple 6 ecommerce web sites, where each B2B customer gets his/her own pricing for thousands of products sold on the sites. Some customers even get their own product descriptions and some don't, but should be able to search either way.
We are planning to replace 3rd party search with SOLR and would like to know how to set it up, so that customer A won't get customer B data(products, descriptions, and/or pricing), and so on. I am not sure if we need to one index per customer or large index with a unique token per customer's records when indexing the data.

Current records size: close to 30 million combinations for 1000s of customers. Simply assume that each customer has their own products, pricing, and descriptions. Also pricing, manufacturer and many other custom facets, so the customer can drill down to what they are looking for.

These are B2B sites where each customer get their own pricing and custom names/descriptions of the products sold. 
Example scenario:

```
item_number name    price
----------- ------- -------
123     Brush     $1.00 -- customer A might call this as 'MyBrush' and customer B as 'TomBrush'
234     shirt -- $20.00
112     pencil -- $1.50

Customer A pricing and descriptions.

item_number name    price
----------- ------- -------
123       MyBrush   $1.00
234       shirt     $20.00
112       pencil    $1.50

Customer B pricing and descriptions.

item_number  name     price
-----------  ------  -------
123         TomBrush  $1.10
234         shirt     $23.00
112         pencil    $1.70

Customer C pricing and descriptions.

item number name 
123     CBrush -- $1.11
234     shirt -- $13.00
112     pencil -- $2.70
```

and so on for thousands of customers, which result in 30 million pricing records, but customer A shouldn't se customer Customer B items and pricing.

Comment: I guess you need to store the `customer` information which document while indexing. When you make the query to solr for search, always use the Customer field as filter and provide only that customer information. Keep this control in your application, without exposing it to the external users.

Comment: Thanks for the information. If I understand it right, I need to attach customer specific unique text/id for every product(or document in SOLR terminology), and use the same id/text while querying along with actual search text. Also we need to be able to update this information everyday for some customers, for pricing and other changes. Do you think keeping 30 million records in one index perform better and the indexing completes in reasonable time? Or should we create one index per customer?

Comment: What is total size of the data and configuration of the machine where you are planning to setup. Also you split the indexes with solr cloud setup.

Comment: The data is close to 100GB and growing. No constraints on the servers since we use internal virtual servers and can request as many as servers and configuration we need.

Comment: I would suggest you to go for [SolrCloud](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/SolrCloud) mode with 5+ shards. Also after indexing data will require approx 1.75x to 2x space. Start playing with it and see what configuration can suit you better.

Comment: Great, thanks again. Would SOLRcloud work like Hadoop parallel processing, in case we need to re-build full index of 100GB, or some other approach is recommended?BTW, how do I rep you for the answers since these are all part of the comments?

Comment: SolrCloud is used when size of the index is large/increasing load on service, that can become bottleneck for the application. It is not like hadoop processing, but incoming search requests will be sent to each of the shard and combined results will be sent to the application. I would suggest you to spend some time with apache solr documentation. It explains everything.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Hadoop type processing on the index side, not from a client  search requests from the application, to SOLR server.

Comment: In SolrCloud, a document will be sent to a specific shard and get indexed. I am not getting you completely.

Comment: I get it now, so we have to split 100GB data from database tables among 5 or more different shards for indexing process, which I believe would be parallel processing. I am reading SOLR in action book, and going through examples and SOLR docs as well.

Comment: You need not to split the data, solr will do it for you. Please go through some example and [Shards and Indexing Data in SolrCloud](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Shards+and+Indexing+Data+in+SolrCloud). You can use the Solr Java API for interacting with solr.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your inputs. I have enough information, so started setting up SOLR in local and will work on production like set up, when I finish setting up the day for 4-5 customers in local testing.